# Error en Pivot suma de totales Oracle Sql

Tags: oracle, pivot

Sigo tratando de poder realizar la suma de totales en una columna agregada usando Pivot, me esta marcando error en la primar linea enseguida del punto despues del PivotTable. El error que obtengo al ejecutarla es el siguiente:

`FROM keyword not found where expected`

La consulta que tengo es la siguiente:

```
    SELECT *, COALESCE(PivotTable.[MEXICO I (52)],0) + --Me alerta de error "FROM keyword not found where expected
           COALESCE([MEXICO II (56)],0) +
       COALESCE([MEXICO III (55)],0) +
       COALESCE([MEXICO IV (62)],0) +
           COALESCE([MEXICO V (63)],0) +
       COALESCE([MEXICO VI (65)],0) +
       COALESCE([MEXICO VII (96)],0) +
       COALESCE([MEXICO VIII (86)],0) +
       COALESCE([MEXICO IX (59)],0) +
       COALESCE([MEXICO X (58) HARNESS],0) +
       COALESCE([MEXICO XI (81)],0) +
       COALESCE([MEXICO XII (83)],0) +
       COALESCE([MEXICO XIII I AND II (50)],0) +
       COALESCE([MEXICO XIV (33)],0) +
           COALESCE([MEXICO RBE XV (37)],0) +
           COALESCE([MEXICO RBE XVI (38)],0) +
       COALESCE([MEXICO XVII (38) NORTH],0) +
       COALESCE([MEXICO XVIII (93)],0) +
       COALESCE([MEXICO XIX(61)],0) +
       COALESCE([MEXICO XX (64)],0) AS topSeal --Columna con suma de totales
       FROM
     (
     SELECT a.report_plant, 
     d.comp_part_nbr, 
    SUM(a.harness_volume *d.occurs) sealVol
    FROM 
    RPTDBA.T56W A
    INNER JOIN RPTDBA.T56Z D
    ON
    a.part_nbr = d.part_nbr
    AND
    a.mfg_plant_id = D.mfg_plant_id
    INNER JOIN RPTDBA.T57A E
    ON
    d.comp_part_nbr = E.comp_part_nbr
    AND
    D.mfg_plant_id = E.mfg_plant_id
    WHERE e.category_1_cd = 'SEAL'
    GROUP BY a.report_plant, d.comp_part_nbr)
    AS Totales
    PIVOT (
    SUM(sealVol) 
    FOR report_plant IN  ([MEXICO I (52)] AS "A",
                                             [MEXICO II (56)] AS "B",
                                             [MEXICO III (55)] AS "C",
                                             [MEXICO IV (62)] AS "D",
                                             [MEXICO V (63)] AS "E",
                                             [MEXICO VI (65)] AS "F",
                                             [MEXICO VII (96)] AS "G",
                                             [MEXICO VIII (86)] AS "H",
                                             [MEXICO XI (59)] AS "I",
                                             [MEXICO X] AS "J",
                                             [MEXICO XI (81)] AS "K",
                                             [MEXICO XII (83)] AS "L",
                                             [MEXICO XIII AND II (50)] AS "M",
                                             [MEXICO XIV (33)] AS "N",
                                             [MEXICO XV (37)] AS "O",
                                             [MEXICO XVI (38)] AS "P",
                                             [MEXICO XVII (38) NORTH] AS "Q",
                                             [MEXICO XVIII (93)] AS "R",
                                             [MEXICO XIX (61)] AS "S",
                                             [MEXICO XX (64)] AS "T"
                                                                     'TOTAL' AS TOTAL
)) PivotTable
ORDER BY topSeal DESC
```

Entiendo que el error es en el FROM pero si tengo agregado el FROM en el query, espero puedan ayudarme a corregir el problema.

De antemano gracias.